# SYSTEM user and SQL server authentication

Tags: c++, sql-server, windows, authentication

I have some problem with stored procedure execution from code which uses windows authentication.

My process is running on SYSTEM account.It executes a stored procedure which works fine if I login WINDOWS with Administrator.But if I log in windows with another user which is not an Administrator I get a permission denied error.

I can solve this by adding the user as SQL server login and grant the execute permission.

But my doubt is why is it not working even if the process is running on SYSTEM account.Does it have admin privilege? Or is it because it's not part of SQL Server login.

The same SP can be executed from VBS via WSCRIPT on cmd which is made to run as Administrator even if I login WINDOWS with another user.

Comment: I am struggling to understand your question. What do you mean by "My process is running on SYSTEM account"? Is it SQL Server process or client process? Please note that SPs execute under the security context of the database user/login. This is how SQL security works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/overview-of-sql-server-security

Comment: Thank you.Its client process.I got the issue,the process was impersonated to windows login.